# Difficulty understanding how to construct different smooth structures on a manifold using the identity map

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

I am reading a text stating:

“It is easy to give examples to show that a $C^{\infty}$ homeomorphism need not be a diffeomorphism. For any integer $n > 1$ the map $x^{2n-1}: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ is such an example, since the inverse does not have a derivative at $0$. **If we change our viewpoint and consider the $C^{\infty}$ homeomorphism as the identity map on an underlying topological manifold, we get examples of different $C^{\infty}$ structures on the same space,** although the resulting manifolds may be diffeomorphic under another map. The example given then shows that if we take $\{x^{2n-1}\}$ as a basis for a $C^{\infty}$  structure on $\mathbb R$ we get different structures for different $n$’s.”

How is it possible to construct different smooth structures using the identity map? Also apparently every function $x^{2n-1}$ gives rise to a smooth structure, how?

Comment: The different smooth structures are $\mathbb{R}$ with the identity map as smooth atlas, and $\mathbb{R}$ with atlas $x^{2n-1}$. Maybe you should look at the definition of smooth manifold to clarify what a smooth structure is; it is just a topological manifold with a smooth atlas. The key observation is that if your atlas has only one chart then you can take any homeomorphism and it will immediately induce a smooth atlas.

Comment: But by definition in the book, an atlas is maximal so they give rise [not] to the same smooth structure as the inverse is not smooth, thanks @GiuseppeBargagnati

Comment: Ok, there is another definition of smooth manifold which doesn't ask for a maximal atlas, and these definitions are indeed equivalent; each smooth structure "belongs" to a unique maximal atlas, and two structures belong to the same atlas iff they are compatible; see for example https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiable_manifold.